# Website unable to connect to SQL Server

Tags: windows, networking, sql

I have a very specific problem which has been plaguing me for months now.
The issue is this:

Every once in a while, the website will lose all connection to the SQL Server with the following error

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.**

I have ruled out the usual solutions to this problem:

1. The username and password for the SQL authentication are correct
2. The SQL Server and my PC can see each other on the network just fine

It usually fixes itself after a certain time, or if I reset my network adapter.

Can you give me any solutions?

The network configuration is as follows:

- Cisco Router (with DHCP, Firewall and VPN configured)
- Cisco Switch (out-of-box configuration)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 with MS SQL Server 2005, 2008 R2 and 2012 instances, TFS and SourceSafe
- Windows 7 acting as file and web server

I don't know the actual router and switch versions, I can post them first thing Monday if it will help.

Comment: Since resetting the network adapter works, you might want to try updating the drivers, or using an alternate network adapter (or even computer).

Comment: That is not really a solution, because the issue appears on 2 development PC-s and the in-house web server, and they are all using the motherboard network adapter (Realtek NIC). The main problem is that in more development-intensive days, the error will appear 5-6 times in a day, and other times, it may appear once a week, even less.


Btw, the Router is Cisco RV042, and the switch is Cisco SG200-26, if it helps

Comment: Do you have static ips?

Comment: The servers do, the development machines are on DHCP